# Java : Error Extract URL without WWW from a String

Tags: java, url

I trying to extract an url from a string, here is the string :

`Hello my name is John. My blog is john.com`

I can't extract that url (`john.com`) because it's not contains `www`

I use the following expression from extract the url :

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$])
```

but still doesn't work.

Please help me how to extract the url without www

Noted :
I have tried all the similar problem on `stactoverflow`, but still doesn't works

Comment: Your regex requires a www or ftp

Comment: I don't recommend capturing `john.com` as URL as the string might have mistakenly connect sentences without spaces such as `Hello my name is John.My blog is john.com. This is gonna be open for public viewing by end of June.Come visit my blog.` But if you insist, you should make your www or ftp optional in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Regex which I used in my project

```
public static List<String> extractUrls(String sms) {
List<String> containedUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
String text = sms;

// Split the sms to analyze if each part is a URL
String[] split = text.split(" ");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(@)?(href=')?(HREF=')?(HREF=\")?(href=\")?(http://)?[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+(\\.\\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+)+(/[#&\\n\\-=?\\+\\%/\\.\\w]+)?");

// Attempt to convert each item into an URL
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if (p.matcher(split[i]).matches()) containedUrls.add(split[i]);
}

return containedUrls;
}
```